# Schedule a program to run at a certain time on Windows CE?

Tags: c#, scheduled-tasks, windows-ce

Is it possible to dictate when you want Windows CE to start a program at a certain time? I want to run a small C# program that I wrote for the device during a specific time. For example I might want the program to start running automatically at 7:00 p.m., and end at 1:00 a.m.

Answer (score 1):

You may use the CeRunAppAtTime API:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms908103.aspx
On some devices the execution may be started also when the device is in suspend mode (waking it up), on other devices only when it's running. This depends on the hardware and BSP, so it's better to check your device documentation if you need also wake up from suspend.